# Google Consent Screen - Asking user consent for every login

Tags: google-identity

I am implementing authorization code flow using Google's new Identity services library https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client.

I have the below code for initializing the code flow:

google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
client_id: this.clientId,
prompt: 'none',
scope: this.scope,
ux_mode: 'popup',
callback: (response) => { ... } });

I am setting the 'prompt' to 'none' and expecting that the consent screen won't appear for every login, but looks like the property is overwritten in the "Choose an account" popup url.

The text "To continue, Google will share your name, email address, language preference, and profile picture with..." is also added to the popup.

Since user already provided the consent in the first request, we would like to avoid asking the consent second time. Could you please help me understand why the 'prompt' property is ignored/overwritten in initCodeClient()?

Comment: Looks like the property 'prompt' is not available for Authorization Code Flow, it is only in implicit flow. Does it mean the consent screen always show up if it is auth code flow? Is there a way to turn the consent screen off?